# why won't my for loop work to print out value in the text file?

Tags: java, arraylist, bluej

I know it is something simple but for some reason i cannot get this loop to work. Help is much appreciated

```
public Instructor()
    {
        // initialise instance variables
        writeMap = new HashMap<String,String>();
        notRecognised = new ArrayList<String>();
        help = new FileHelper();
        notRecognised = help.readAList("missed.txt");
        for(String i : notRecognised.length) {
            System.out.println(i);

        }
    }
```

Comment: Do you expect `notRecognised.length` to return a `String`?

Answer (score 2):

Your enhanced for loop isn't correct. Use the list, not it's length

```
for (String i : notRecognised) {
    System.out.println(i);
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You'll want to iterate over a collection, not over a length:

```
    for ( String i : notRecognized )
```

See the bottom example in the [Java `for` tutorial](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/java/nutsandbolts/for.html).

Answer (score -1):

Probably missed.txt is empty and hence the help.readAList() function returns empty String.

```
 notRecognised = help.readAList("missed.txt");
```